# How can I export the component class and that class method?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, unit-testing, tdd, jestjs

For jest test file I want to import component and that method.

For example I have this component :

```js
import React from 'react'

class Dashboard extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props)
    }

    sum(one, two) {
        return one + two
    }

    render() {
        return(
            <div>
                <h1>{this.sum(12, 14)}</h1>
            </div>
        )
    }
}

export default Dashboard
```

So, in the test file I like to test component with render and sum function with toEqual :

```js
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import Dashboard from '../Dashboard';

it('check component', () => {
    const div = document.createElement('div');
    ReactDOM.render(<Dashboard />, div);
});

it('check sum function', () => {
    expect(sum(12, 12)).toEqual(24);
});
```

But the second test and sum has failed, because the test function could not find sum function ...

How can I export component and that contain method ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If you want test a function, that doesn't depend on a component you can use `static` modifier:

```js
import React from 'react'

class Dashboard extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props)
    }

    static sum(one, two) {
        return one + two
    }

    render() {
        return(
            <div>
                <h1>{Dashboard.sum(12, 14)}</h1>
            </div>
        )
    }
}

export default Dashboard
```

```js
it('check component', () => {
    const div = document.createElement('div');
    ReactDOM.render(<Dashboard />, div);
});

it('check sum function', () => {
    expect(Dashboard.sum(12, 12)).toEqual(24);
});
```

In most cases it isn't necessary to test react-component methods separately.

Another way to solve you problem is move sum to separate module. Then you can add unit tests to this module.

Comment: Thanks, I solved it with `Dashboard.prototype.sum` in the test file and just with `import Dashboard from '../Dashboard'`